# Disappearance of header while scrolling to anchor of a webpage inside Iframe

Tags: iframe, anchor

I have a webpage with a header and an iframe (outer) for loading different webpages as content.  One of the webpage also have an iframe (inner) and sidebar. While loading webpages to the inner iframe works, when I click  to jump to specific anchor of the webpage, the header outside the outer iframe disappeared. How to resolve this?

Code for outer iframe

```
    <body>
    <header>
    <img src="image" height="100px" style="float: left; ">
    <h1><center>text</center></h1>
    <div class="navbar">
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction0()">Welcome</button>
      ...
    </div>  
    </header> 

    <iframe id="Myinframe" 
    width="100%"
    height="600px"
    style="border: none;"
    src="welcome.html"
    </iframe>
    </body>
```

Code for sidebar and inner iframe:

```
     <body>
     <div class="container">
     <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="1.html" target="content">Text</a></li>
          ....
        <li><a href="4.html#anchor" target="content">Text</a></li> 
     </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="content">
      <iframe name="content" src="default.html"></iframe>
     </div>
     </div>
     </body>
```

I expect the header part to stay intact whatever I change in the iframes. However, while jumping to 1.html works, when 4.html#anchor is clicked, the header will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the header was scrolled out. So instead of fixing the height of the outer iframe, I used  height: calc(100vh - 150px) to subtract the header and it works.